# How to set or find the command name of a Sublime Text plugin

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I am trying to write an ST3 Plugin for my node js server. In order to run it I am calling the command `view.run_command('Node js.nodejs')`.

My Sublime Text `Packages` folder looks like this:

```
│   main.py
│   text_example_one.py
│
├───Node js
│       Nodejs.py
│
└───User
    │   main.py
    │   Package Control.last-run
    │   Package Control.sublime-settings
    │   Preferences.sublime-settings
    │
    └───Package Control.cache
            01524fae79697630d0454ba3fabd9414
            01524fae79697630d0454ba3fabd9414.info
```

The `../Packages/Node js/Nodejs.py` file contains the following code:

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class TryCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        print("It's working")
        self.view.insert(edit, 0, "Hello, World!")
```

Nothing at all happens when `view.run_command('Node js.nodejs')` is called, see [the image of the window here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei96n.png).

No errors are raised but the `"Hello, World!"` message is not inserted and `"It's working"` is not printed in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plugin does not get called by the `view.run_command('Node js.nodejs')` command.

To run your plugin you need to call the `try` command, e.g. `view.run_command("try")`. Here is the explanation of why:

The command names of Sublime Text plugins are derived from their **class names**. For example the following class...

```py
class PrintHelloInConsoleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        print("Hello")
```

...can be run by calling the `print_hello_in_console` command. e.g.

```js
// Run from a plugin or in the console
view.run_command("print_hello_in_console")

// Run from keys by adding a key binding
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+y"], "command": "print_hello_in_console"},

// If instead of a TextCommand the plugin had been a sublime_plugin.WindowCommand
// then the following line would be needed to run the command in the console.
window.run_command("print_hello_in_console")
```

To get the *command name* from the *class name* first remove the `Command` postfix from the class name. Second convert what remains of the class name from `CamelCase` into `snake_case`. So a plugin which defines `class PrintHelloInConsoleCommand` is called by the `print_hello_in_console` *command*.

- The class name is: `PrintHelloInConsoleCommand`
- Remove *Command* from the class name:
  `PrintHelloInConsoleCommand --> PrintHelloInConsole`
- Convert *CamelCase* to *snake_case*:
  `PrintHelloInConsole --> print_hello_in_console`
- The name of the command to call is: `print_hello_in_console`

Your class, `class TryCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand)` can be run by calling the `try` command, i.e. `view.run_command("try")`.

---

Here are some other examples:

- `class ClearConsoleCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand)`
  ⟶ `"clear_console"` command
- `class InsertDateTimeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand)`
  ⟶ `"insert_date_time"` command
- `class TestOKCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand)`
  ⟶ `""` No command created — do not use a word in uppercase, e.g. the `"OK"` in `"TestOK"`. Note that this does not create a `"test_o_k"` command
- `class MoveSelection(sublime_plugin.TextCommand)`
  ⟶ `"move_selection"` command — this works despite the omission of `"Command"` in the class name. At the time of writing that requirement is not strictly enforced by ST (but that may change in future versions)
- `class AutoSaverEvents(sublime_plugin.EventListener)`
  ⟶ `""` No command created — event listeners do not get called so no command is created and ST does not expect the class name to end in `"Command"`

For further information about plugins, see the [plugins section](http://gohom.win/ManualHom/IDE/Sublime/sublime-text-unofficial-documentation-3.0/#plugins) of the Sublime Text [Unofficial Documentation](http://gohom.win/ManualHom/IDE/Sublime/sublime-text-unofficial-documentation-3.0/index.html#document-index) which has a lot more information than the official documentation has.