# Sublime Text 3 snippets with date and time as custom variables

Tags: sublimetext3, code-snippets

I am trying to make a custom snippet in sublime text 3 with custom environment variables.

I essentially want to include today's date in my snippet, but there is no official support for this environment variable.

I have tried many solutions from the stack overflow, but unable to get it done. Most of them are outdated.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do exactly that with a Sublime Text snippet.

I suggest you take a look at what is informally called a `Snippet Macro` in the documentation of the [InsertDate plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/InsertDate) on *Package Control*.

The InsertDate plugin's author, *FichteFoll*, suggests the creation of a macro to insert a snippet and which then automatically moves snippet fields to insert the date. Below is FichteFoll's example macro from the plugin's page. You could copy'n'paste it and save it in your `User` folder as `DateSnippet.sublime-macro`.

```json
[
    { "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "Date: $1\nTime: $2\nSomething else: $0"} },
    { "command": "insert_date", "args": {"format": "%x"} },
    { "command": "next_field" },
    { "command": "insert_date", "args": {"format": "%X"} },
    { "command": "next_field" }
]
```

The `insert_date` command clearly requires the InsertDate plugin to have been installed. Install that using *Package Control* or use a plugin as lightweight as the one below that I wrote for a similar reason, which can be called with the `insert_todays_date` command (see *How to set or find the command name of a Sublime Text plugin* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63979147/2102457)).

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin, time
class InsertTodaysDateCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        # The date/time field codes for strftime() are at this url:
        # https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime
        date_today = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        for sel in self.view.sel():
            self.view.insert(edit, sel.begin(), date_today)
```

To run the macro you could call it from the Sublime Text menu `Tools --> Macros`, create a *Command Palette* entry for it, or just add a key binding with something like this:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+y"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/DateSnippet.sublime-macro"} },
```

Comment: Can this macro be integrated with the outer snippet?? If yes, how?

Comment: You can't call a macro from a snippet if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Or any other way to call that command "run_macro_file" with arguments "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/DateSnippet.sublime-macro"} } from snippet. Or any other way so that I don't have to use the macro and directly add the date and time when the snippet is triggered?