# How to copy current file full path without filename using right click menu?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import os
class copypathCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self,edit):
        # view = sublime.active_window().active_view()
            vars = self.window.extract_variables()
            working_dir = vars['file_path']
            base_name=os.path.basename(working_dir)
            sublime.set_clipboard(base_name)
            print ("get clipboard" + sublime.get_clipboard())
```

Context.sublime-menu

```
[
    { "caption": "copypath",  "command": "copypath"},
]
```

This script doesn't work.
When I use ctrl-v,it pastes "working_dir".
I think the problem is `sublime_plugin.WindowCommand` parameter or the `self.window.extract_variables()` because I only change this two line from other working fine copyfilename script.
[menu button turns grey when add if statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXJ5A.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plugin contains several errors and places where the code can be improved.

1. The `os.path` class is not automatically imported using `import os`. You need to use `import os.path`.
2. Your class name `class copypathCommand` must begin with a capital `C` to create the `copypath` command, i.e. `class CopypathCommand`, see [How to set or find the command name of a Sublime Text plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63979147/2102457).
3. You have inherited from `sublime_plugin.WindowCommand` but then used the `edit` parameter in the `run()` method which can only be used in classes that inherit from `sublime_plugin.TextCommand`. It is best to use a `TextCommand` for this plugin since it will already have the active view set as `self.view`. So that gives `class CopypathCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand)`.
4. There is no need to use `extract_variables()` to get the file path. The [Sublime Text API](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) provides the `file_name()` method in the `view` class which returns the full file path or `None` if the view / buffer is unsaved (i.e. no file path to return). So the full path can be retrieved with one call `file_path = self.view.file_name()`.
5. You use `os.path.basename()` but your question title says you want the "*current file full path without filename*" which would require the use of `os.path.dirname()`. This is how those 2 methods differ in what is returned:

```py
os.path.basename("/full/path/to/folder/filename") --> "filename"
os.path.dirname("/full/path/to/folder/filename")  --> "/full/path/to/folder"
```

Putting it all together for a working plugin gives the following code:

```py
# Save in ST config folder: ../Packages/User/CopypathToClipboard.py

import os.path, sublime, sublime_plugin

class CopypathCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit):
        file_path = self.view.file_name()
        if not file_path:
            sublime.status_message("The current buffer is not saved")
            return
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(file_path)
        sublime.set_clipboard(dir_path)
        sublime.status_message("Copied folder to the clipboard: " + dir_path)

    # is_enabled() enables the plugin only if the view contains a saved file.
    # If this returns false the 'copypath' command will not be available,
    # e.g. command palette captions hidden, context menu captions greyed out.
    def is_enabled(self):
        return True if self.view.file_name() else False
```

There is nothing wrong with your `Context.sublime-menu` code — although adding the `id` line, as I have done below, means that the command's caption `Copy Folder Path` will be displayed in the same menu section as `Copy File Path` in the right-click context menu.

```json
// Save in ST config folder: ../Packages/User/Context.sublime-menu
[
    { "caption": "-", "id": "file" },
    { "caption": "Copy Folder Path",  "command": "copypath"}
]
```

Comment: Thanks,that is great answer for me. There is one more question:sometimes the button turns into grey."command" value in context menu should be lower case.Is that right?

Comment: To have the command greyed out in the context menu when there is no path available the `is_enabled()` method needs to be implemented — see my edited plugin above. Yes the `"command"` value in the context menu should be in lower case, ALL Sublime Text commands are lower case, see [How to set or find the command name of a Sublime Text plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63979147/2102457).

Comment: Another problem is that sometimes I follow your code add ```if statement```,the menu turns into grey immediately,when I remove,the button turns to black again function well again.Is there something wrong with the ```if statement```

Comment: Re: "Another problem" — I do not understand your question. Please ask someone who speaks good English to help you to write another comment which explains what you mean.

Comment: Sry I am not very clear about the question due to comment format limit,I updated a gif in the question description!Feel free to check!

Comment: RE: Your [EXJ5A.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXJ5A.gif) file — I have no idea what is happening in that `gif` but I am unable to reproduce the results. Commenting out the if statement clause should make no difference at all in a view/buffer that has been assigned a disk location, i.e. it has been saved at least once.