# Sublime Text 3 sublime_plugin.WindowCommand

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3

I have a sublime text window open which contains many 'files'
I would like to be able to run a plugin I have written which does some checks on the contents of each file.

I can't get started with the sublime_plugin.WindowCommand.

Here is the start of my efforts.  It does not return any errors, but does not return anything.

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class StuffCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        my_views = self.window.views()
        for a_view in my_views:
            file = a_view.file_name()
            print(file)
        print("Finished")
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you add more to your question, like how you're trying to trigger the command, where you saved the file, and if you see any errors in the Sublime console when you save?

Comment: It works for me too. Maybe Chris omitted the required `imports`, I've added them to the post. If it's how to run the plugin that's needed then the easiest is to run it from the console, which is also where the file names will be printed, with this command: `window.run_command("stuff")`.
See my answer to the post [How to set or find the command name of a Sublime Text plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63979147/2102457) if you're unclear why the command is `stuff`.

Answer (score 0):

OdatNurd is on the right track.
I was entering a view.run_command in the console.
I created a key binding so that I was able to execute the code whilst the window containing the files was the focus, and it worked okay.